# Am I a dependent child for UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a student that is currently studying at a university in UK on a short term study visa (I am not a non-visa national, so I had to apply before arrival). My parents are in the process of applying for a visa to visit me for 2 weeks. In their application, it asks if they have any dependent or non dependent children traveling with them. We will be travelling together in the UK during those 2 weeks. I am 21 years old, so I am not sure if I am considered a dependent or non dependent. My parents do support me financially and that was stated in my visa application.

Should they put me as a dependent or non dependent child? The only dependence is financial.

Comment: You are currently in UK and your parents are travelling to see you (not along with you), The question is "Any dependants travelling with you?". You should mark as no dependants travelling along with you.

Answer (score 6):

The [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424265/VAF1-GUIDANCE-NOTES.pdf) for questions 4.19 and 4.20 is as follows:

> **4.19 Please list any of your children who will be travelling with
>   you to the UK?**
>   Please note that any children travelling with you may also need a
>   visa.
>   If they need a visa, they will have to complete their own application
>   form.
>
> **4.20 Will any other children be travelling with you?**
>   Answer Yes/No. This is any other children under 18 years of age,
>   who are not your own children, but that will accompany you to the
>   UK. Please note that if they need a visa, they will have to complete
>   their own application form.

As you can see, this refers to children who are travelling *with* them from their point of origin to the UK. This doesn't describe your situation; instead, they are visiting you in the UK. They will explain this in detail in part 8 of the [application](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424264/VAF1A-VISITOR__SHORT-TERM_STUDY___PARENT_OF_T4__CHILD__STUDENT.pdf), which asks who they are visiting and which family members live in the UK.

If they feel further explanation is required, they can write whatever they wish in the Additional Information section.

Finally, it is a very good advice to read the guidance while filling out the application. Following it carefully can help avoid errors or other mistakes that might cause the visa application to be refused.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but 4.17 still asks for a list of dependent children. Should I be listed there? I am also using the online application, which has slight differences from the paper version, so the guidance sometimes doesn't fully align with the application.